# Two Spaces Automatically Converted to &nbsp (Heroku, Mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, meteor

I've been trying to build a disussion website, using the [Telescope](https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope) engine. Installing on Heroku with a MongoHQ plugin is a piece of cake, but I've found problem that I can't replicate on my machine (the problem only exists in Heroku's instance).

Say, I want to write some code in Markdown for comment, so I added four spaces before a line, like this:

```
    // some piece of code
```

And the string, straight from mongodb comes out as this:

```
&nbsp; &nbsp; // some piece of code
```

which is weird because it's saved as

```
    // some piece of code
```

(with the four spaces) in database. I'm not sure if this is Heroku's server doing or some setup in MongoHQ (and I can't find any setting in both). Is this some sort of limitation from Heroku's free instance? Or is it some setting in mongo?

What should I do to fix this?

Thanks before.

Comment: I can safely say that MongoDB is not doing the conversion.  This is due to something further up the stack.

Comment: @WilliamZ thanks. I'm not really sure what's the problem here, but I can safely remove mongo from consideration for now...

Comment: Are you using `contenteditable` elements anywhere?

Comment: @matt: nope, no content-editable...

Comment: With your reference to the string "straight from MongoDB", where are you checking this .. in the `mongo` shell or via your application code?  It would be helpful to confirm if the string is actually saved incorrectly or if the spaces are a display issue.  I've seen similar issue with spaces added by textarea WYSIWYG editors such as CK Editor; generally this is behaviour you can override in the editor configuration.

Comment: @Stennie: I checked directly from the mongo shell. There's no `&nbsp` there, so I'm pretty sure it's not saved incorrectly. Also, the problem can't be replicated on my machine(s). This problem only comes out when deploying on Heroku, that's why I think it must be configuration error on the Heroku side...

Comment: It would help to know how exactly you are fetching the document from Mongo and displaying it on your web page. That's where the screw up is happening. Are you sure you are using the exact same javascript code/library versions, if any?  Also, you have tagged your question with node.js. Can you tell where does node.js come to play here? Are you using it to fetch or store data via Mongo or something?

Comment: You can try `console.log()` the value, it should show in heroku log somehow. Also try sending out the value with spaces replaced (e.g. `.replace(/ /g, '_')`) to figure out whether it gets replaced before this point or after it.

Comment: I know with Rails apps you have to be very careful to keep your development environment clean, and you must always use `bundle exec [command]` when trying things on your local machine, because the Heroku environment is kept pristine.  From the Heroku docs, it looks like node.js uses `npm` in much the same way that rails uses `bundle`. Make sure everything your app needs is in your `package.json` file and wipe out any plugins installed locally. Copy your `Procfile` from Heroku and run `foreman start` on your local machine.  If that doesn't reproduce the error, then I don't know.

Comment: When you mean straight from mongodb do you mean if you look for this on the client end via the console or on the web page (in any way e.g handlebars, etc..). Have you tried running locally in production mode?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like to me that whatever is reading in the document from mongodb is automatically converting 2 spaces into "nbsp; " which makes sense because you can't just chain together a billion spaces in a row, you have to alternate "nbsp; " + space or just use a bunch of chained "nbsp; " characters.

I would search any third party libs that you're using for "nbsp; " exactly and see what you find. That will have to lead to an answer.

Note: You'll need to add in an & before each nbsp; char, SO converts them to a space otherwise and if you escape it, then it ignores the trailing space.

Comment: @derek, the reason I reverted your edit is because the way you formatted it removed the emphasis on that the key string to search for was an nbsp; AND a space both next to each other. Without the quotes being output that important detail got lost on your revision.